# Write json to .txt file

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, json.net

im serializing a List of string to a Json string and then generating a File from the json string but for some reason my file doesnt have the "{}" of my json.
This is my List Serialization:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach(item in Model){list.Add(item)}

var reqUsers = list;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqUsers);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\path.txt", json);
```

My path.txt show this:

```
["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50",0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"$26.50"]
```

But i need my output like this:

```
[["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50",0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"$26.50"]]
```

My foreach loop to fil my list:

```js
 for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                        {
                        var value = 0;
                         if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
                                                    total += value;
                         }
                                                   list.Add(item.Descripcion);
                                                   list.Add(item.Pdv);
                                                   list.Add(item.Rid);
                                                   list.Add(((costo / (total + 1)).ToString("C")));
                                                    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        var value = 0;
                                                        list.Add(value.ToString());
                                                        int month = item.Fecha.Month;
                                                        if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; list.Add(value.ToString()); }
                                                       
                                                    }
                 list.Add(total.ToString());
                 list.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));
                        }
```

i want each time my list finish a serie of the foreach loop to make the data enclosed by []
How can i do this?

Comment: your json output is `list of list of string`, not `list of string`

Comment: and what is the correct syntax? its my first time converting a list to json

Comment: `var reqUsers = new List<List<string>> { list };` maybe you can try this code

Comment: Ir kinda worked but i have more rows that what i show in my example and im only getting the [] on the first and last spot is there a way to put them on all rows?
like this:
[["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50",0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"$26.50"]
["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50",0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"$26.50"]]

Comment: then it's no longer *valid* json, if you really want this format, you need to write custom code

Comment: mmm to my list or how can i make this format?

Comment: Don't use the Snippet button for code that's not executable javascript/css/html.

Comment: "doesn't have the "{}" of my json"? Can you please edit post to clarify what output you are looking for. Also consider showing JSON that match your code - there is no way strings will be serialized to numbers like the post shows `0,1,0` .

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need your output to be like that. But if you want it that way, you can do something like this.

```
        List<List<List<string> > > arrayArrayList = new List<List<List<string>>>();
        List<List<string>> arrayList = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("Hello");
        list.Add("Hello1");
        list.Add("Hello2");            
        arrayList.Add(list);
        arrayArrayList.Add(arrayList);

        list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("bye");
        list.Add("bye1");
        list.Add("bye2");
        arrayList =  new List<List<string>>();
        arrayList.Add(list);
        arrayArrayList.Add(arrayList);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayArrayList);
```

In this case your output will be `[[["Hello","Hello1","Hello2"]],[["bye","bye1","bye2"]]]`

**Updated the answer based on the recent update to the question.**

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.Append("[");
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
   buffer.Append("[");
   foreach(var item in items)
   {       
      buffer.Append("\"\"");
      buffer.Append(item.Pro1);         
      buffer.Append("\"\"",");
       //add other props
   }
    buffer.Append("]");
}
buffer.Append("]");
File.WriteAllText(path,buffer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your current object being serialized in another collection so that it will be serialized the way you want:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<object>() { list });
```

This should put another "[" and "]" around your current serialized text.